# How to find out if integer_sequence contains given number in compile-time?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

Given:

```
typedef std::integer_sequence<int, 0,4,7> allowed_args_t;
```

and:

```
template<int arg> void foo()
{
    static_assert( /*fire if arg not in allowed_args_t!*/ )
}
```

How should I write that `static_assert` to be as cheap as possible in compile-time?

I'm using C++17.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to use:

```
template <int ... Is>
constexpr bool is_in(int i, std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
{
    return ((i == Is) || ...);
}


typedef std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 4, 7> allowed_args_t;


template<int arg> void foo()
{
    static_assert(is_in(arg, allowed_args_t{}));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that unpacking `...` can be used in such way! I'll accept this in 5 minutes (I seriously don't know who added such limitation onto StackOverflow...)

Comment: Fold expression has been added in C++17, and requires around parenthesis.

Comment: Will be nice to have template lambdas in C++20 so we can do this all inline: https://wandbox.org/permlink/hT6R6SxcEQtVFcsj

Answer (score 8):

Unpack the integers and use a fold expression:

```
template <typename AllowedIntegers>
struct contains
{};

template <typename Int, Int... Is>
struct contains<std::integer_sequence<Int, Is...>>
{
    template <Int value>
    static constexpr bool contains = ((value == Is) || ...);
};

// ...

template <int arg>
void foo()
{
    static_assert(contains<allowed_args_t>::contains<arg>);
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/bkW-cS)

Comment: Nice, I've upvoted that - but @Jarod42 answer is just shorter :)

Comment: @PiotrK Indeed. The only real benefit this answer provides is that it enables partial application. I also have a hunch that this *might* be faster in terms of how long it takes to compile, but it depends on how the templated variable works and how often you call them with different values; I'd have to measure to be sure.

Comment: @Justin: as `value` to check in both cases are not part of template value, it should not create extra instantiations and so I expect similar compilation time. But as you said, the only ways to be sure is to measure.